# ADFS authentication with PWA

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, adfs, progressive-web-apps

I would like to log in my users through ADFS2.0(OR 3.0, I think it has no difference at all) but into the scope field, I can only insert a subpath of the same DNS. How to redirect to ADFS and get the token back using PWA?

any suggestions?